# C# .NET OpenID Connect tutorial requires editing hosts file, but I don't have admin rights?

Tags: c#, .net, openid-connect

In an effort to learn how to use net7.0's `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` library at my workplace, I am following an online tutorial (https://curity.io/resources/learn/dotnet-openid-connect-website/).

The problem is, the tutorial requires one to edit the local machine's hosts file, as follows:

`127.0.0.1  www.example.com login.example.com`

As I am using my company Windows 11 laptop for this tutorial, I do not have admin permissions, which are required to edit the hosts file.

Is there an alternative way to accomplish what I need to accomplish (i.e. mapping `127.0.0.1` to the two urls `www.example.com` and `login.example.com`) *without* modifying hosts - and which doesn't require admin privileges?

Comment: Why are you even trying to do software development on a machine that doesn't allow Admin access, LMAO...

Comment: @IanKemp Actually it is a good practice not using admin access when using a computer. Following a programming tutorial should absolutely not require admin access at all. Think about children practicing in school lab.

Comment: use @ToreNestenius's answer: replace www.example.com and login.example.com in your tutorial with localhost or localtest.me.

Comment: @IanKemp these days it is the exception rather than the rule (and in my experience a very rare exception indeed) that companies grant their software engineers local admin rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use https://localtest.me and https://localhost as two different domains locally, they both point to 127.0.0.1.

For more information about localtest.me, visit https://readme.localtest.me/

Then I use

```
mkcert -pkcs12 -p12-file localtestme.pfx localtest.me
```

To create a locally trusted certificate. MkCert can be found at https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

Comment: Wouldn't trusting a domain not under your own control dangerous?

Comment: Works fine for local development, sure ,you should not use it in production, but for test and local dev i see no problems.